# How to make a Http Request with as2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Is it possible to make a simple Http Request using as2 and get the redirected result?

**Example**

I make a request to http://www.somesite.com/loader?params using as2 which redirects to

http://www.redirectedUrl.com/somefile.swf

I want to be able to access and store the address of the redirected url (in the above example that would be http://www.redirectedUrl.com/somefile.swf url

Comment: Is it a MUST to use Action Script 2?

Comment: In this case it is. Believe me, if there was any of way I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LoadVars class to the job